# Post-switch hook in TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm trying to set up a post-update hook in TortoiseSVN. It runs just fine when I do an SVN Update, but switching branches does not cause the hook to run.  The [TortoiseSVN documentation](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#id725647) states that a post-update hook is "Called after the update, switch or checkout finishes (whether successful or not)."

Does anyone know how to get the hook to run after a switch as well?